# Memcache - how to determine order of a timeline

Tags: memcached

I am building something that is like Twitter's tweets.

I am currently storing each individual object/tweet under a single key in memcache, this is good for viewing the individual object/tweet page. If I want to get all of the things in order by the created date for display in a timeline format, I'm stuck.

I was thinking of creating another key to store the recent 100 objects' ID, and use these IDs to get the individual objects. Is there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Redis, lists are specifically used for modeling a timeline.
Similar to that in memcached, a separate timeline object can be maintained containing the top n or (recent) IDs. A limit can be maintained for the timeline object so that it will store only 'n' IDs. 
Ex: Incase of twitter, when a user tweets, the message ID will be added to the top of the timeline object. And when the user scrolls down, the timeline object can be updated by batch prefetching.

Comment: Thanks. I have created another key to store the top 1000 IDs, is that considered a lot?

Another problem I'm having is I'm trying to implement infinite scrolling as well, but if I get 1000 items, I'm not utilizing it well. But if I keep only 20 items per key, I have to keep updating my memcache if people keep creating new objects.